# Vue- How can I control the behavior of chips in v-autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-autocomplete

I have a 20-25 names coming from API where I'll need to show them in a drop down box (requirement). I'm using Vue v-autocomplete here to display the selected names on the field. I've used custom item called `Select All` where the user can select all the names in the drop down list, but what I also need to do when the user clicks on Select All is that I don't want to show all the names in the Autocomplete field including Select All Chip. Only items that are selected individually without Select All should show as Chips.

Here is my code sandbox I've attempted so far. I'm new to Vue js, so I'm hoping to get some thoughts on controlling the chips on v-autocomplete.

[v-autocomplete sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-2-v-text-field-forked-kkngdn)

Comment: Your sandbox does not work - when I try to select any option individually then nothing happens. Only if I choose `Select All` then all options are selected. You will need to use the `selection` slot and render chips only for those options which are not called/named `Select All`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of including "Select All" in the array of names, you can use the [prepend-item](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-autocomplete/#slots-prepend-item) slot to include a separate Select All checkbox.

If you need to differentiate between names selected via individual click and those selected via the Select All checkbox you will probably need a new property in the names array to track that, say a boolean that is true if selected one way and false the other.

You'll also need a slot like [selection](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-autocomplete/#slots) to customize the display of your chips where you can use `v-if` to conditionally render a chip based on that new boolean property.

This [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-2-v-text-field-forked-621neh?file=/src/App.vue) I believe is pretty close to what you're after

Comment: Thanks mate. I'll take this. I would have done this in react using renderInput attribute in Autocomplete but I wasn't aware of selection slots in Vue. This certainly helps.

Comment: No problem! It's not specifically "selection slots" that are a thing, but [slots](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html) in general that component authors sometimes provide to help users customize specific parts of their components.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the tip mate. I attempted to modify based on your comments to update the selection slot to add (+3 more) if the selected names goes more than 5. 

Here is the sandbox I forked from yours. Any hints on what could have gone wrong? 

https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-2-v-text-field-forked-ruug0b?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: the selection slot evaluates itself for **every** selected item.  it's meant to be a way to customize every item the same way.  so if you don't somehow limit the "(+x more)" to display only once, it'll display for every selected item that passes your `v-if` check.  trying to still follow your requirement of keeping all items selected with 'Selected All' to be hidden but now also hiding all items if there would be more than 5 v-chips, this is what I came up with: https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-2-v-text-field-forked-fdyppo?file=/src/App.vue